# Classic ASP cannot execute stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I can execute the query in SQL Management Studio successfully. ASP code throws an error.

```
        Response.Write "<hr>" & sql & "<hr>"            
        conn3.Execute sql
```

ASP Error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server hata '80040e07'
>
> Error converting data type varchar to smalldatetime.

SQL query:

```
exec db.dbo.stored_proc1 @artID='6226', 
  @Odeme_Date='3-27-2013 15:47:24', @Odeme_Valor ='3-27-2013', 
  @OnceAnapara=0, @GecZamHemen= 1, @ODENEN_TUTAR = '263.69' , 
  @Odeme_Tip=3, @BankID=62, @MakbuzTanimID=45, @BilinmeyenID=NULL, 
  @CariAvansID=NULL, 
  @USERID=62, @MakbuzNO=NULL, @SelectedID='(817843)', 
  @Mesaj=NULL, @idleriGosterme=0, @CariCekID=NULL, 
  @CariSenetID=NULL
```

I can copy & paste the query then execute it successfully. What's wrong with ASP?

Comment: Your issue isn't ASP, it's ADO. I don't think you're executing the query you think you are. ADO is treating everything purely as a string. What you need to do is create an `ADODB.Command` object (for the SP itself) and `ADODB.Parameter` objects (for the parameters passed to it). My Classic ASP/ADO is really rusty; see [this page](http://clarksoncs.com/Samples/ADOParamQ.htm) for a starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with your server settings regarding date formats (from your parameter names, looks like you are probably not using USA date formatting).  Try checking your "dateformat" on the target database:

```
use db
go

DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

Regardless, you should *always* format date strings in one of the "unambiguous" formats: YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD.  So I would change the date parameter string values:

```
@Odeme_Date='2013-03-27 15:47:24', @Odeme_Valor ='2013-03-27'
```

Comment: So do I. But same query has been executed in Management Studio without error.

Comment: I agree it does not make much sense.  Did you try changing the date formats to YYYY-MM-DD?  There is a lot that happens between Connection.Execute and SQL Server that may not happen when you execute from SSMS.

Comment: In parameterized version I used YYYY-MM-DD version.

Answer (score 2):

I used parameterized query and it worked.

This link helped to find data type values: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_datatypes.asp

PS: Do not use query string version of @Var_Date; ie "MM-DD-YYYY" as parameterized input. Use parameter in "YYYY-MM-DD" format.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from the provider, so it really does see a datatype mismatch.  It may run in SQL Server Management Studio, but still fail in the provider.  I would look at the date literals again and try variations in the date formatting, and see if you can get that to work.

If the provider won't pass a varchar at all, then you might have to rewire your stored procedure to accept varchar parameters, and convert them to date types inside the procedure.